# How can I render a object type with Backbone forms?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-forms

Define:

```
schema: {
    salutation: {
        type: 'Select',
        validators: ['required'],
        editorClass: 'form-control',
        isRequired: true,
        title: 'Salutation',
    },
    address: {
        type: 'Object',
        subSchema: {
            address: {
                type: 'Text',
                validators: ['required'],
                editorClass: 'form-control',
                isRequired: true,
                title: 'Address',
            },
        }
    },
```

And in my template, I use `data-fields` to render fields:

```
<div data-fields="fieldname"></div>
```

How can I load elements from `subSchema`?